# Add and delete clone?

Tags: jquery

Must have made a small mistake. There is a jsfiddle that I've worked on. I am trying to get the add and delete buttons working.

They also have a hide and show element that I haven't included but it shouldn't matter?

http://jsfiddle.net/27N7Y/

HTML:

```
<div class="question">
<div class="questiontext">
    23. Have you or anyone included in this application ever previously applied for a visa or travelled to Australia?
</div>
<div class="questionradioanswer">
    No <input type="radio" id="notravel" name="previousvisa" value="No" class="radiobutton">
    Yes <input type="radio" id="yestravel" name="previousvisa" value="Yes" class="radiobutton">
    </div>
    <div id="question23hide">
        Provide dates of previous visits to Australia<br>
        <select id="selectday6" class="daydate">
            <option>Day</option>
            <script>
                var select = document.getElementById("selectday6");
                var options = new Array();
                var temp = 1;
                for (var i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
                options.push(temp);
                temp++;
                }
                for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                var opt = options[i];
                var el = document.createElement("option");
                el.textContent = opt;
                el.value = opt;
                select.appendChild(el);
                }
            </script>
        </select>
        <select id="selectmonth6" class="monthdate">
            <option>Month</option>
            <script>
                var select = document.getElementById("selectmonth6");
                var options = ["January", "Febuary", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
                for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                var opt = options[i];
                var el = document.createElement("option");
                el.textContent = opt;
                el.value = opt;
                select.appendChild(el);
                }
            </script>
        </select>
        <select id="selectyear6" class="yeardate">
            <option>Year</option>
            <script>
                var select = document.getElementById("selectyear6");
                var options = new Array();
                var firstyear = (new Date().getFullYear()) - 18;
                var temp = firstyear;
                for (var i = 0; i < 83; i++) {
                options.push(temp);
                temp--;
                }
                for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                var opt = options[i];
                var el = document.createElement("option");
                el.textContent = opt;
                el.value = opt;
                select.appendChild(el);
                }
            </script>
        </select>
        </div>
        <div id="adddeleteprevious">
            <div id="addprevious">
                <input type="button" class="button" value="Add Previous Visits">
                </div>
                <div id="deleteprevious">
                    <input type="button" class="button" value="Delete Previous Visits">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

JQUery:

```
$("#addprevious").click(function(){
    $(".question23hide:last").after($(".question23hide:first").clone(true));
});

$("#deleteprevious").click(function() {
    if($(".question23hide").length!=1)
        $(".question23hide:last").remove();
});
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Could you be more specific?

Comment: the add button which is cloning the div and the delete button which is deleting an added div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there were so many mistakes...
first you should learn how to debug, install firebug and use console.log(), to check if you are accessing the the click's to see, if you are getting the selcted item...

```
console.log($(".question23hide:last")) 
//Result no Object matched, oh you try to access id not class..
```

much worse:

```
$("#addprevious").click(function(){
      console.log("am i clicked"); 
      //no! you try to click on a div, but you want to click on the button inside...
});
```

here is the fiddle study it..:
And, script tag inside a select? no need for that:...

http://jsfiddle.net/V7yp6/1/